# subject length issue while sending email using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When subject of email is too long then getting following error

```
The following SMTP error was encountered:


451 See
http://pobox.com/~djb/docs/smtplf.html. Unable to send email using
PHP SMTP.  Your server might not be configured to send mail using
this method.
```

And when shortened the subject length, it works fine.My `smtp config` setting is

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp'; $config['smtp_host'] = 'host';
$config['smtp_port'] = '**'; $config['smtp_user'] = $email_id;
$config['smtp_pass'] = $password; $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n"; $config['crlf']    = "\n"; 
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE; $config['wrapchars'] = 10;
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you google the error message?
'Your server might not be configured to send mail using
this method.'

Comment: No idea about CodeIgniter but... what size are we talking about? 200 char? 2,000? 20,000,000,000?

Comment: Your crlf should be \r\n too I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known issue, caused by email *Subject* with more than 75 chars:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/154493/P15/#925385

It **might** help to change the email config. There are two ways to go about it:

1. Create a separate instance of the email object with its own separate config parameters: `$email = new CI_Email(array('newline' => "\r\n"));`
2. Using the in-line config strings: `$this->email->newline = "\r\n";` and `$this->email->crlf = "\n";`